# Limiting the number of checkboxes selected in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

currently I have a signup form with 5 options but I'm trying to find a way to limit so the user can only select 2 options and in case the user selects a third option the first one would be unchecked, I had found a way of doing this in plain js but I haven't found a react way of doing it. This is what I have so far, would it be better to handle with plain js instead of react?

```
{iconsPool.map((src, index) => (
  <Box className="test">
    <input type="checkbox" className="iconsCheckbox" id={iconsPool.id} />
    <label for={iconsPool.id}>
      <img className="signupIcons" src={iconsPool[index].src} key={index} />
    </label>
    {console.log(iconsPool)}
  </Box>
))}
```

Comment: What happens if the first box is rechecked? What box gets unchecked? The last one? The second one?

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented with a state as an array with 2 elements.
Two items of the state Array will represent the index of selected items.

If an checkbox is clicked, that checkbox and the one clicked right before will be checked. (Therefore unchecking the one that was clicked even before that)

This can be done by pushing the index of newly clicked checkbox into the head of array, and removing the last item of the array.

When an checked checkbox is clicked again, (therefore it should be unchecked,) the index of the checkbox is searched from the state array, and removed by replacing that value with `undefined`

Below is code, as an example

```js
...
const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState([undefined,undefined])

// When an Item is clicked
const onClickItem = (itemIndex:number, isSelected: boolean) =>{
  if(isSelected){
    setCheckedItems(c=>([itemIndex,c[0]]))
  } else {
    if(itemIndex === checkedItems[0]){
      setCheckedItems(c=>([undefined,c[1]]))
    } else if(itemIndex === checkedItems[1]){
      setCheckedItems(c=>([c[0],undefined]))
    }
  }
  
}
```